# return false If Value Is Not Numeric

Tags: jquery

The following is validation for a form I have created. I include the function step_2_validation() on submission of step 2.

The function correctly spots if the inputs contain a string, but the form does not break with the return false; statement. What am I missing here?

```
// Check mileage does not contain text
var mileageInputs = $('.form__item.labelled input[type="text"]')
var mileageArray = $.map(mileageInputs, function(value, index) {
    return [value];
});

var stringArray = [];

for(var i=0;i<mileageArray.length;i++){
    var thisValue = mileageArray[i].value;
    var thisValue = thisValue.replace(/\,/g,''); // remove commas added during input
    if ( $.isNumeric(thisValue) == false && thisValue != '' ) {
        stringArray.push(thisValue);
    }
}

if ( stringArray.length > 0 ) {
    alert('This should stop the form... it does not');
    return false;
}
```

Comment: The above change (off the back of @Jamiec's comment) fixed the problem - I was calling the function wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that the `return false` that you have simply halts the execution of the each, it does not return false from your outer function `step_2_validation`.

One option is to revert to using a good ol' `for(...)` loop, which *will* return out of the outer function when it hits the `return false`.

```
for(var i=0;i<mileageArray.length;i++){
    var thisValue = mileageArray[i];;
    thisValue = thisValue.replace(/\,/g,''); // remove commas added during input
    if ( $.isNumeric(thisValue) == false ) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Note that you almost certainly want a `return true` after that `for(..)` loop, otherwise the return value from your function will always be falsey.

Comment: After `for` should be a `return true;`, or not? Otherwise the check would be always `falsy`.

Comment: @eisbehr - I guess so probably, but it wasnt in the OP's original code. You're almost certainly right though - without that the result of the function will *always* be falsey (either `false` or `undefined`). Take note OP!

Comment: Thanks for feedback guys; I've managed to get it working to the point that the 'alert' message flags up correctly!! However the 'return false;' statement simply doesn't stop the form from proceeding. There must be something buggy somewhere else in the code?

Edit: I've updated my OP with the new code using the for loop.

Comment: @Nick I suspect your form looks something like `<form onsubmit="myValidation()">` when it should look like `<form onsubmit="return myValidation()">`